# Unwanted gray text after editing main-style

Tags: css, wordpress, editor

On WordPress site, I've edited some code in main-style.css in browser, after saving that changes it worked fine but showing some unwanted text, it happened previously and I had backup of main-style.css and restoring that solved the issue, but this time edited it without any backup, can anyone please help with it, is it character set issue, uni code or ascii etc

```
    .wss-tabs-content .wsstc-thin{
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.wss-tabs-content .wsstc-thin .wsstct-col{
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(136,136,136,0.3);
}
.wss-tabs-content .wsstc-thin .wsstct-col:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}
.wss-tabs-content .sec-heading{
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.wss-tabs-content .wsstc-desc{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.wss-tabs-content .wsstc-desc p{
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.wss-tabs-content .wsstc-list{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.wss-tabs-content .wsstc-list li{
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1.1em;
}
.wss-tabs-content .wsstc-list li:before{
    content: '25A0';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0.2em;
    color: #888888;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.3em;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.wss-tabs-content .wsstc-list li .wsstcl-link-ext{
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 85%;
}
.wss-tabs-content .wsstc-list li .wsstcl-link-ext:hover{
    color: #007c39;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[image: Gray text on start of each line]

Comment: We cannot answer this question without seeing the code in question. Please post the relevant parts of the `main-style.css` file.

Comment: Thank you Ken, I've added code from related section of screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as I suspected; somewhere along the way a bullet point got converted to a Unicode value:

```
.wss-tabs-content .wsstc-list li:before{
    content: '25A0';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0.2em;
    color: #888888;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.3em;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

One the second line, `content`, the `25A0` is most likely supposed to be a [Unicode Character 'BLACK SQUARE' (U+25A0)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a0/index.htm). According to the linked page, the HTML entity representation should be `&#x25a0;`; if we type that literally in here we see ■, the correct character (at least I presume that it how it should look!).